# onClick, Transfer values to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that does couple of things when user performs `onClick`

- Creates an object in an array.
- Adds random values to 3 of its (i.e., objects) keys and then creates component with those values.

I have component that shows those values.

What I want is when I click `LaunchResult` #5 I need to show this value in another components . And When I click `LaunchResult` #10 that components that show values have to change to values that in the `LaunchResult`.

I tried to lift up and save in the bigger array, but I think it is a bad idea.

Code https://codesandbox.io/s/problem-vy0z6i?file=/src/App.js

Comment: what is #5 and #10 here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I completely understand the question, but here is your example with a context which is useful if you don't want to do prop drilling. `Valueslist` has the same values as the randomly generated numbers when the button is clicked.

Code: [https://codesandbox.io/s/problem-forked-ig1mhr?file=/src/App.j](https://codesandbox.io/s/problem-forked-ig1mhr?file=/src/App.js)s

**numberContext.js**

```js
import { useContext, createContext, useState } from "react";

// Create empty context
export const NumberContext = createContext();

// Create a hook to use the context
export function useNumberContext() {
  return useContext(NumberContext);
}

// Create context provider, wrap the provider around the parent component
// whos children you want to recive the values
export function NumberContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [valuelist, setValueList] = useState([]);
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    Diameter: 1,
    Friction: 1,
    Quantity: 1
  });

  function setValue(key, newValue) {
    setValues({ ...values, [key]: newValue });
  }

  function getRandNUm(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  const addValueList = () => {
    let a = getRandNUm(0, 10);
    let b = getRandNUm(0, 10);
    let c = getRandNUm(0, 10);
    setValues({
      Diameter: a,
      Friction: b,
      Quantity: c
    });
    setValueList([a, b, c]);
  };

  return (
   /* set the values and function you want to access */
    <NumberContext.Provider
      value={{
        values: values,
        valuelist: valuelist,
        setValue: setValue,
        addValueList: addValueList
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </NumberContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

**App.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
// import the context and the NumberContextProvider to wrap components
import { useNumberContext, NumberContextProvider } from "./numberContext";

function LaunchResults({ launchName }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="launchName">{launchName}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

function ValueContainer({ valueName }) {
  // access the values from the context
  const { values } = useNumberContext();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{valueName}</p>
      <div className="valueContainer">
        {/* Get the value assigned to valuName key */}
        <span>{values[`${valueName}`]}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export function Container() {
  // Access the context
  const { valuelist, addValueList } = useNumberContext();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* Run addValueList function from context on click*/}
      <button onClick={addValueList}>Dead</button>
      <>
        {valuelist.map((item, item_id) => (
          <LaunchResults
            key={item_id}
            launchName={item}
            launchDiameter={item.diameter}
            launchFriction={item.friction}
          />
        ))}
      </>
      <ValueContainer valueName={"Diameter"} />
      <ValueContainer valueName={"Friction"} />
      <ValueContainer valueName={"Quantity"} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    // Wrap the Privider around the consumers then you can access
    // context inside container and all its children
    <NumberContextProvider>
      <Container />
    </NumberContextProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you please explain it with the context here, that link might go down in the future.

Comment: I added the code here and some comments, hope that clarifys it.